# Use * in bash script

Tags: bash, glob

There are more than a few questions about this, but I can't seem to get it right.

I've got a script that assigns a particular path to a variable and adds a filename with an * in it. If the path has a space in it, I can't get the script to evaluate correctly.

Let's say the variable is set to something like:

```
var="/path/with/a space/in/it/"*.jpg
```

if I try something like

```
for i in $var
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

the script won't find any files at all and will just spit back out the value of var with the * in it, split into two at the space:

```
/path/with/a
space/in/it/"*.jpg
```

So is there a way to get it to process the variable as a proper path?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395836/bash-script-quote-issues) was some help, but it doesn't quite work as I'd like.

Comment: Why are you setting var?  Are you going to use the information stored in it for something other than being used in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is bash, you can make `var` an array (see [this Unix.SE question on expanding globs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34011/the-best-way-to-expand-glob-pattern)):

```
shopt -s nullglob

var=("/path/with/a space/in/it/"*.jpg)

for i in "${var[@]}"
do
  echo "$i"
done
```